# Associating Multiple Commands with one key in .xbindkeys

Tags: xbindkeys

How can I run several commands in succession when a key is pressed?  For example,

```
"Command 1"
"Command 2"
"Command 3"
   Hotkey
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Associate a single command which runs the three commands successively. The command is always executed via a shell (specifically, via `/bin/sh`).

```
"Command 1; Command 2; Command 3"
  Control+F42
```

Comment: `&&` can be used as well if the following command depends on the previous one to run (conditional succession) - it is the logical `AND` operator - if the first results in `true` the second runs, else not